# SBT Coverage "exclude" used in Play application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scoverage

I used the sbt-scoverage for our Play application.

I used the following config to exclude both Reverse and Routes generated file.

```
coverageExcludedPackages := ";Reverse.;Routes.;"
```

However this can only exclude generated Reverse scala files and can't exclude Routes files. Even I use the following script, it does the same

```
coverageExcludedPackages := ";Routes.*;"
```

Anyone knows what is the correct regex should be?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As an improvement to @socom1880's answer, this worked for me by adding it to `build.sbt`

```
coverageExcludedPackages := "<empty>;Reverse.*;router\\.*"
```

Comment: To ignore modules in subprojects/submodules, add the above line to the settings of the submodule. See https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/issues/96

Answer (score 3):

Try

`coverageExcludedPackages := "<empty>;router\\..*;"`

Comment: Add it where? Your answer doesn't seem to address the question very well.

Comment: Updated. I think it would have been clear to the asker where to add it, but I updated it for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Better to try the below configuration:

`coverageExcludedPackages := ".*Reverse.*;Routes.*"`

This will definitely work.