# Scoverage how to exclude files and packages?

Tags: scoverage

I am trying to exclude packages and files from the scoverage report.

However it does not exclude the specified files and packaged.

I am doing this:

```
<excludedPackages>*api.test.*</excludedPackages> 
<excludedFiles>.*File.scala</excludedFiles>
```

Could someone suggest how it works for you ?

Cheers
V.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44346781/2370679

Add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

To exclude packages (e.g. to exclude `*api.test.*` and `*api.db*` packages):

```
coverageExcludedPackages := "<empty>;*api.test.*;*api.db*"
```

You can also use the syntax to exclude files:

```
coverageExcludedPackages := "*File.scala"
```

For your specific example, you can try:

```
coverageExcludedPackages := "*File.scala;*api.test.*"
```

Reference: https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage#exclude-classes-and-packages

Comment: why we are adding `<empty>;`, can you please explain in detail?

Comment: This is incorrect. According to the referenced link, you must use regex (not GLOB), which match only against fully qualified class names and not file names.

Comment: I am getting an error "Dangling meta character '*' near index 0"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing this right, though I'm not familiar exactly with the Maven plugin which you seem to be using.

Thing is, when scoverage excludes files, it still compiles the classes in them, but it doesn't instrument them, resulting in a `.class` file identical to one which will be produced by compilation without the plugin. This might be confusing you to see `.class` files for classes originated in source files you explicitly excluded -- it sure did confuse me -- but this is how the plugin works.

**Update:**

The Scoverage scalac plugin will try to match file paths to the regex **after** removing `.scala` from them; i.e, omit the `.scala` from your regex as it will never match any file pattern.

Also note that the regex is matched against *paths* and not class names; i.e, use `/` instead of `\.`. Can't say if this works on Windows (if not then it's a bug with the scalac plugin).

Answer (score 1):

In my `build.sbt` I was able to exclude classes using the following line:

`coverageExcludedPackages := "<empty>;.*ExcludeThisClass;.*BuildInfo",`

Note: The initial `<empty>;`was required for it to pickup on the first exclusion. Not sure why this is, but it matches the explanation by their readme:

- https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage#exclude-classes-and-packages